# Routing to other subnets results in wrong ARP requests

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, arp, ip-routing

I would like to manually set up routing to subnet 95.168.0.0/16 through IP which is an alias: 94.23.94.161. IP alias is set up like that:

```
 /sbin/ifconfig eth0:0 94.23.94.161 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 94.23.94.161
```

At the beginning i tried something like that:

```
route add -net 95.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 94.23.94.161 dev eth0
```

and everything worked just fine, until i got an email from my datacenter that IP address is sending wrong ARP packets:

```
Wed Jun 6 08:07:15 2012 : arp who-has 95.168.204.130 tell 94.23.94.161
Wed Jun 6 08:37:13 2012 : arp who-has 95.168.204.130 tell 94.23.94.161
Wed Jun 6 09:07:19 2012 : arp who-has 95.168.204.130 tell 94.23.94.161
```

Conversation with their support went to nothing and now i'm still trying to fix that. Another setup which worked (but still was sending these wrong ARP packets) was:

```
ip route add 95.168.0.0/16 via 94.23.94.161
```

i think this one internally worked just the same.

Next i tried configuring routing through iptables and SNAT. I enabled ip-forwarding and tried  different crazy stuff like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 94.23.94.161 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 95.168.0.0-95.168.255.255
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 94.23.94.161 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 95.168.0.0-95.168.255.254
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 95.168.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 94.23.94.161
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 94.23.94.161 -j DNAT --to-destination 95.168.0.0-95.168.255.254
```

None of these changed routing. Could anyone give me any sort of advice how to change route to this subnet without sending spare/wrong ARP packets?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Where would you like packets bound for 95.168.204.130 to go? (Your machine is sending the ARP packets because it has no idea which machine to send those packets to. How is it supposed to know?) Is `94.23.94.161` assigned to *this* machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ip addr add 94.23.94.161/32 brd 94.23.94.161 dev eth0
ip route add 95.168.0.0/16 src 94.23.94.161 via 176.31.243.253
ip neigth flush
```

Where 176.31.243.253 is gateway

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, `94.23.94.161` is the IP address of some machine on your LAN that you want to route packets bound for `95.168.0.0/16` to. If that's correct, either of your two route statements will do the job. Just get rid of the aliased `eth0:0` interface. That's for *local* IP addresses assigned to *this* machine.

Comment: If i undestand you correctly, you suggest removing the alias... I can't do that because this alias is one of my additional IP addresses ("ip failover" technology of OVH - http://www.ovh.co.uk/dedicated_servers/ip_failover.xml http://help.ovh.co.uk/IpFailover)

Comment: Oh, then it should be assigned to a loopback interface, not an Ethernet interface.